# How to condense 5 click event functions of similar code into one function

Tags: javascript

So I am currently trying to make a design responsive based on click events but it's being done into 5 different for loops

What the function does is that there are five customization question and each question has three answers in a div box. For each question, if I click on one of the answer div box, the box will be styled differently (ex: .preference-selected) and if I click a different answer within the same question, the previously selected div box will go back to it's default style and the currently selected div will have the class .preference-selected.

For clarity:
Each customization answer has a class according to the question. For example, the first for-loop is a question to "How you drink your coffee?" and each listed answer has a class "preference-option" and so on.

The following code below works but I'm wondering if there's a way for me to shorten the code with purely JavaScript. I see a lot of answers online uses JQuery. I just started learning programming so I want to focus on purely JavaScript first and not jump around outside the scope of my focus. If the code below is the best option to what I'm currently learning, please let me know how I can turn it into one contained function (if it's possible). If not, what can I do to make it better with just JavaScript?

Thank you very much!

```
var preferenceSelected = document.getElementsByClassName("preference-option")
for (i=0; i < preferenceSelected.length; i++) {
    preferenceSelected[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        var selected = document.querySelector(".preference-selected")
        if (selected) {
            selected.classList.remove("preference-selected");
        }
        this.classList.add("preference-selected");
    }, false);;
}

var beanSelected = document.getElementsByClassName("bean-option")
for (i=0; i < beanSelected.length; i++) {
    beanSelected[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        var selected = document.querySelector(".bean-selected")
        if (selected) {
            selected.classList.remove("bean-selected");
        }
        this.classList.add("bean-selected");
    }, false);;
}

var quantitySelected = document.getElementsByClassName("quantity-option")
for (i=0; i < quantitySelected.length; i++) {
    quantitySelected[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        var selected = document.querySelector(".quantity-selected")
        if (selected) {
            selected.classList.remove("quantity-selected");
        }
        this.classList.add("quantity-selected");
    }, false);;
}

var grindSelected = document.getElementsByClassName("grind-option")
for (i=0; i < grindSelected.length; i++) {
    grindSelected[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        var selected = document.querySelector(".grind-selected")
        if (selected) {
            selected.classList.remove("grind-selected");
        }
        this.classList.add("grind-selected");
    }, false);;
}

var deliverySelected = document.getElementsByClassName("delivery-option")
for (i=0; i < deliverySelected.length; i++) {
    deliverySelected[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        var selected = document.querySelector(".delivery-selected")
        if (selected) {
            selected.classList.remove("delivery-selected");
        }
        this.classList.add("delivery-selected");
    }, false);;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a single method

```
function addClickListener(searchClass, destinationClass) 
{
    let classElements = document.getElementsByClassName(searchClass)
    for (let i = 0; i < classElements.length; i++) {
        classElements[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            var selected = document.querySelector("." + destinationClass);
            if (selected) {
                selected.classList.remove(destinationClass);
            }
            this.classList.add(destinationClass);
        });
    }
}
```

And then initialize your elements with

```
addClickListener("preference-option", "preference-selected");
addClickListener("bean-option", "bean-selected");
addClickListener("quantity-option", "quantity-selected");
addClickListener("grind-option", "grind-selected");
addClickListener("delivery-option", "delivery-selected");
```

Comment: Hi Luca, quick question, why did you add a false boolean at the end of the function? What does that mean?

Comment: I didn't remove the extra parameter from your functions code, it was useless actually.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, why don't you create a function and pass the things that change as parameters, with that you can avoid duplicate code.

```
var preferenceSelected = document.getElementsByClassName("preference-option")
var beanSelected = document.getElementsByClassName("bean-option")
var quantitySelected = document.getElementsByClassName("quantity-option")
var grindSelected = document.getElementsByClassName("grind-option")
var deliverySelected = document.getElementsByClassName("delivery-option")


function handleSelected(elements, className)
  for (let i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
     elements[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        var selected = document.querySelector("." + className)
        if (selected) {
            selected.classList.remove(className);
        }
        this.classList.add(className);
    }, false);
}

handleSelected(preferenceSelected, "preference-selected");
handleSelected(beanSelected, "bean-selected");
handleSelected(quantitySelected, "quantity-selected");
handleSelected(grindSelected, "grind-selected");
handleSelected(deliverySelected, "delivery-selected");
```

Comment: Vo Quoc Thang, I added the second argument (the className) to each of the calls to `handleSelected`.

Answer (score 0):

While there are several ways to do this, the best choices will probably involve [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation). (In this example, click events bubble up to the "container" div, and the listener checks which button was clicked.)

Here, each option has a "category" (preference, bean, or quantity), which appears in a [custom attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) as well as on the option's class list so the listener can easily loop through all related options to update the styles.

```js
// Calls `changeSelections` when something in container is clicked
const container = document.getElementById("container");
container.addEventListener("click", changeSelections);


// Defines the listener
function changeSelections(event) {

  // Gets event's target and ignores irrelevant clicks
  const clickedThing = event.target;
  if (!clickedThing.classList.contains("option")) {
    return;
  }

  // Gets category from custom attribute and identifies matching options
  const
    category = clickedThing.getAttribute("data-category"),
    relatedOptions = container.getElementsByClassName(category);
  //console.log(category); // -> preference, bean, or quantity

  // Loops through related options, unselects all and re-selects clicked
  for(let option of relatedOptions){
    option.classList.remove("selected");
    if(option == clickedThing){ option.classList.add("selected"); }
  }
}
```

```css
.group {
  width: 5em;
  margin: 1.2em;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.option {
  margin: 0.1em;
  padding: 0.2em 0.3em;
  border-radius: 0.4em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.selected {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="group">
    <div class="option preference" data-category="preference">Pref 1</div>
    <div class="option preference" data-category="preference">Pref 2</div>
    <div class="option preference" data-category="preference">Pref 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <div class="option bean" data-category="bean">Bean 1</div>
    <div class="option bean" data-category="bean">Bean 2</div>
    <div class="option bean" data-category="bean">Bean 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <div class="option quantity" data-category="quantity">Quant 1</div>
    <div class="option quantity" data-category="quantity">Quant 2</div>
    <div class="option quantity" data-category="quantity">Quant 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```